# Sorting of weights(gm, milligrm, litre, mili litre.)

Tags: java, compare, sorting

In a column "Size", I have weights like  100mL , 0.5mg, 1L, 2500cm2. I need to sort it out according to ml, mg, gram, litre, cm etc. Please give me solution for it, I have tried with String Comparison but its not worthable as we have to consider weights.

```
 public static int safeCompareIgnoreCase(String name1, String name2) {
      if (name1 == name2) { 
        return 0; 
      } 
      if (name2 == null) { 
        return -1; 
      } 
      if (name1 == null) { 
        return 1; 
      } 
      return name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2); 
    }

    public int compare(InventorySearchResultRecord r1, InventorySearchResultRecord r2) { 
      int result = safeCompareIgnoreCase(r1.getSize(), r2.getSize()); 
      if (result != 0) { 
        return result; 
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: and are you sorting based on weight OR alphabetically?

Comment: Rather than asking for solution straight(which won't help you), you should post your code here. You will get to improve your own code and learn more than if you get a solution..

Comment: Millilitres and litres are units of volume, milligrams are units of mass, and centimetres squared are units of area. Comparing numbers of different units seems a little pointless. If you want the numbers sorted, strip off the units.

Comment: Column sounds like SQL, give us at least a code sample with a basic structure you need.
+ sort by what? just group the different units?
There is no way to sort cm^2 with mg

Comment: public static int safeCompareIgnoreCase(String name1, String name2) {
  if (name1 == name2) {
   return 0;
  }
  if (name2 == null) {
   return -1;
  }
  if (name1 == null) {
   return 1;
  }
  return name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2);
 }

 
 public int compare(InventorySearchResultRecord r1, InventorySearchResultRecord r2) {
 int result = safeCompareIgnoreCase(r1.getSize(), r2.getSize());
  if (result != 0) {
   return result;
  }
 }

Comment: You should use `equals()` to compare two strings rather than `==`

Answer (score 5):

Hint: - You should not compare two values in different units.. Think yourself -> How will you tell whether `1 Dollar` is greater or `50 Rupees`?? You need to convert them into same units..

And first try to do it on paper.. Get your work done without computer.. If you got the answer, convert it to code.. It would be easier for you..